# Django: Collecting all entries from a Foreign key model from a specific Parent Model

Tags: python, django, apache, postgresql

I am currently using this relationship to grab all images from a specific instance of the model `Product`

```
product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
images = product.image_set.all()
```

If I start to delete and rearrange images the set does not update itself properly and includes old images and simply stays in its original order.

I believe a solution to this would be to define `images` by the `Image` model directly, instead of as a set of the `Product`.

doing it this way:

```
images = Image.objects.all()
```

returns all images for every single product. Is there a way I can use a similar method, calling the images from the `Image` model directly, that will target only the active Product's set of images? something along the lines of:

```
images = Image.objects.all(product_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
Image.objects.filter(product__product_id=pk)
```

Or

```
Image.objects.filter(product__pk=product_id)
```

Use the first example if "pk" is a variable and "product_id" is the column name, or visa-versa. Also, note the double underscore after `product` in `filter(product__pk=product_id)`.

Comment: Your solutions both gave errors, but after some messing around based on your suggestions, I have figured it out I think. my images model looks like this: ////
    `product_image = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image',blank=True)`
//// so this ended up working (I think, need to do some more testing)://////

`images = Image.objects.filter(product_image_id=product_id)`